# How to write Case statement in SSIS expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a small condition in SQL Code. How can I write that in SSIS in Derived column task.

```
CASE WHEN SaleProduct IS NULL AND ReProduct IS NULL THEN '' 
     WHEN SaleProduct IS NOT NULL AND ReProduct IS NULL THEN SaleProduct
     WHEN SaleProduct IS  NULL AND ReProduct IS NOT NULL THEN SaleProduct

ELSE 

SaleProduct +';'+ ReProduct  END As COL
```

I have tried with the following expression 
but not getting anything

```
(ISNULL( [SaleProduct]  )&& [ReProduct] == "") : ? "0" 
" ------------------------"
UNKNOWN
```

can anyone help me on this ...

Comment: Firstly... why would you? Just leave it in the SQL. Secondly you have the syntax incorrect. Its `<expression>?<true result>:<false result>`. Your `:` comes before `?`

Comment: no I need to convert this into SSIS and I know that expression is not correct. Can you advice on this @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: step 1: put the `:` and the `?` the right way around. What do you get?

Comment: (ISNULL( [SaleProduct]) && (ISNULL([ReProduct])) ) ? "" : (!ISNULL([SaleProduct]) && ISNULL([ReProduct]) ? [SaleProduct] : ( ISNULL([SaleProduct]) && !ISNULL([ReProduct]) ? [ReProduct] : [SaleProduct] + ";" + [ReProduct]))

Comment: Why couldn't you find an SSIS expression reference guide online?   After guessing, actual research should precede posting forum questions.

Answer (score 0):

CASE statements can be replicated by using Conditional operator in the Derived column transformation.
For your condition the expression would be like

```
((ISNULL(SaleProduct) == True && ISNULL(ReProduct) == True) ? " " :((ISNULL(SaleProduct) == False && ISNULL(ReProduct) == True)? SaleProduct :(ISNULL(SaleProduct) == True && ISNULL(ReProduct) == False)? SaleProduct : SaleProduct+";"+ReProduct)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/conditional-ssis-expression) in `Derived column` transformation:

To understand and depict your condition:

```
  ( ISNULL([SaleProduct]) && ISNULL([ReProduct]) ) ? " " :
       ( !ISNULL([SaleProduct]) && ISNULL([ReProduct]) ) ? [SaleProduct] :
                       ( ISNULL([SaleProduct]) && !ISNULL([ReProduct]) ) ? [SaleProduct] : ( [SaleProduct]+";"+[ReProduct] )
```

**But** tabs causes error in `Derived column` transformation. Hence it should actually be:

```
(ISNULL([SaleProduct]) && ISNULL([ReProduct])) ? " " : (!ISNULL([SaleProduct]) && ISNULL([ReProduct])) ? [SaleProduct] : (ISNULL([SaleProduct]) && !ISNULL([ReProduct])) ? [SaleProduct] : ([SaleProduct]+";"+[ReProduct])
```